# cocos2d collision detection issue

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to detect collisions between a character and platforms in a cocos2d game.

The whole game runs in one class, and is updated in one method: in a previous question it was said that one update method vs many update methods wouldn't have a performance difference.

This is how I check for collisions:

```
if(velY<=0)
{
  if(_guy.position.x<child.position.x+child.contentSize.width/2 && _guy.position.x>child.position.x-child.contentSize.width/2)
  { 
    if(velY/50<5)
    {
      if(((_guy.position.y - _guy.contentSize.height/2) - (child.position.y+child.contentSize.height/2))<abs(10) && ((_guy.position.y - _guy.contentSize.height/2) - (child.position.y+child.contentSize.height/2))>-4)
      {
         //some code
      }
      else if(((_guy.position.y - _guy.contentSize.height/2) - (child.position.y+child.contentSize.height/2))<abs(velY/50) && ((_guy.position.y - _guy.contentSize.height/2) - (child.position.y+child.contentSize.height/2))>=-4)
      {
         //some more of the same code as above
      }
```

The `if(velY/50<5)` is so that if it is moving slow it has a large window it can be within a larger range.

All the sprites on screen are moving, and are all contained in one large batch. In the update method I loop through each child of the batch, and if it is within the `x` and `y` range of the `_guy` (the main character) it sets him on the platform. However sometimes when the guy just makes it over the top of the platform, it seems to miss it, and lets him fall through. I am guessing this is because it takes to long to check each platform? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A missed collision can never be a performance issue. All the update code is run before a frame is rendered, so there must be a bug in the collision detection. Break the checks down into its components instead of cramming multiple calculations in a single if/else if statement. That's terribly hard to debug. Cache some of these values that you use multiple times (ie guy.contentsize.height / 2) to make things easier to read (and minimally faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LearnCocos2D was right, it wasn't a preformance issue. The problem was that I was using this:

```
    ((_guy.position.y - _guy.contentSize.height/2) - (child.position.y+child.contentSize.height/2))<abs(10)
```

But the _guy sprite had extra blank space around the image, so when the even though the image was above the platform the blankspace would not be, and so it wouldn't detect a collision. The following code works much better:

```
    if(abs((_guy.position.y - _guy.contentSize.height/2+15) - (child.position.y+child.contentSize.height/2))<abs(5)){
             if((_guy.position.y - _guy.contentSize.height/2+15) - (child.position.y+child.contentSize.height/2)>0){ 
                 //code
             } 
    }
```